# Iterators over Tries in Java

Tags: java, iterator, trie

I am currently trying to implement a trie data structure for integer tuples. And have implemented as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TrieNode {

int num;
ArrayList<TrieNode> links;
boolean endOfTuple;

public TrieNode(int num)
{
    this.num = num;
    links = new ArrayList<TrieNode>();
    this.endOfTuple = false;
}

}
```

I then have a trie class as follows:

```
public class Trie {

TrieNode root;

public Trie() {
    root = new TrieNode(-1);
}
public void insertTuple(int[] tuple)
{
    int l = tuple.length;


    TrieNode curNode = root;

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        TrieNode node = new TrieNode(tuple[i]);

        if(!curNode.links.contains(node)){
            curNode.links.add(node);
        }
        curNode = curNode.links.get(curNode.links.indexOf(node));
    }
    curNode.endOfTuple = true;  
}
}
```

I can add values to this trie, but i need to be able to iterate over this and was wondering how i could do this?  For example if i wanted to print the tree using an iterator...Any help will be great...

Comment: Google using an iterator for an ArrayList

Comment: Your `curNode.links.contains(node)` line will easily break (or is broken if you forgot to implement `equals()`)  as it depends on the implementation of `equals()`. Try iterating over the links and explicitly compare the link labels.

Comment: yeah it is broken! crap...how do i implement equals? is it in the Node class?

Answer (score 0):

All you need for an interator is to implement the `Iterator` interface, which only requires that you supply `boolean hasNext()` and `Integer next()`. So the question to ask is: how do represent a position in your trie, such that it's possible to (a) fetch the value associated with that position, and (b) figure out the "next" position given a current one?

I'll refrain from posting an actual solution since I'm not sure whether this is homework. But consider: you can represent a "current position" in your trie just by choosing a particular trie node, and the path of trie nodes you used to reach it. Then you can compute the "next" element recursively: if the current element is a node that has children, then find the first child for which `endOfTuple` is `true`. If the current element doesn't have children, then go to its parent and advance to that parent's next child. If that parent doesn't have next children, then go it *its* parent's next child, etc.